# In an MVC application, where will the dependency injection take place?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) and Spring's MVC, where should the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) take place?

Example, if you have a controller, and many actions in the controller.

Would you be doing:

```
@RequestMapping("/blah")
public String SomeAction()
{
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    MyService myService = ctx.getBean("myService");

    // do something here

    return "someView";
}
```

Would this be the best practice approach?  Or is their a better way?

Comment: When using getBean method, it sounds like a Service Locator pattern, not dependency injection. Do not call us (applicationContext.getBean) , we call you.

Comment: Really -- a mrblah question where he doesn't accept any answers?  SHOCKING, I tell you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole idea of Dependency Injection is to **not** have your classes know or care of how they get the objects they depend on. With injection, these dependencies should just "appear" without any request (hence the Inversion of Control). When using `ApplicationContext#getBean(String)`, you're still asking for the dependency (a la Service Locator) and this is **not** Inversion of Control (even if this allows you to change the implementation easily).

So, instead, you should make your `MyController` a Spring managed bean and inject `MyService` using either setter or constructor based injection.

```
public class MyController {

    private MyService myService;

    public MyController(MyService aService) { // constructor based injection
        this.myService = aService;
    }

    public void setMyService(MySerice aService) { // setter based injection
        this.myService = aService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMyService(MyService aService) { // autowired by Spring
        this.myService = aService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/blah")
    public String someAction()
    {
        // do something here
        myService.foo();

        return "someView";
    }
}
```

And configure Spring to wire things together.

Comment: I think it's important for newcomers to Spring MVC to understand that your controller is already being loaded and wired up by an ApplicationContext. Therefore, all you need to do is specify which other beans the controller should be wired up with.

Comment: You could add @Controller to the front of the class above to help Spring load it, especially if you use <context:annotation-config />

Comment: So any wired bean will be instatiated like: AnyBlah blah = new AnyBlah() ?

Comment: @mrblah: Try that out, give it a go. And meanwhile we prepare an answer for your next question. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use getbean, that loses the purpose of doing DI.  Use @Autowired instead. DI is meant to be used in a layered system like view, service, [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), so that each layer is not depending on each other.

Comment: No cometta, one can still clutter things, i.e. make inappropriate dependencies, using DI. Your suggestion is correct, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a compliment to Pascal's post, 
[Martin Fowler: Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) is a must read.

And as cometta stated, that you should use `@Autowire` annotation to achieve that. In addition to that, Spring supports name based and type based convention injections. I suggest you to read on that.